# Springboot SecurityFilterChain

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

im just tryna to learn springbootsecurity and in this bloc there s many error 'csrf()' and 'authorizeHttpRequests()' are deprecated and marked for removal  and theres also problem in JwtAuthenticationFilter it said
Cannot resolve symbol 'JwtAuthenticationFilter'

[image]

[image]

could someone help me  for solving this
public class SecurityConfig {

```
private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

//les listes n est authentifies mais les autres doivent etres authentication
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain SecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception{

    http
          .csrf()
          .disable()
          .authorizeHttpRequests()
        
          .authenticated()
          .and()
          .sessionManagement()
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
      
          .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

    return http.build();
```

Comment: [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html)

Comment: [Securing-web](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/), this 2 resources will be enough to cover this topic

Comment: please do not post any pictures of text ... post text itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();


    }
```